# Cannot read property 'lastIndexOf' of null error when trying to upload a gltf file using react threejs

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf

I am trying to upload a gltf file in reactjs and show it.But i am getting this error in the load function:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastIndexOf' of null
```

this is for the input file:

```
<input id="files" type="file"  onChange={this.handleGltf} type="file"/>
```

This is the onchange fuction where i load the gltf file with three.js:

```
  handleGltf(event) {
        if (event.target.files[0]) {
            this.setState({
                file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
            })
        }
```

I get the error from this gltf loader inside the onchange function:

```
this.loader.load(this.state.file,   gltf => {

                console.log(this.state.file)
                this.gltf = gltf.scene
                console.log("check5")

                // ADD MODEL TO THE SCENE
                this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
    
                this.control.attach( gltf.scene );
                this.scene.add( this.control );

                //
                gltf.scene.scale.set(3, 3, 3)
                this.orbit.update();

                this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
            }, undefined,

            error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: There should be more to this error, as `lastIndexOf` is not in your code, so it's _somewhere_ in threejs or react, but without context there's no way of knowing what went wrong and where. Some method is probably expecting an array, but which? Is it a malformed file? Is it a a decoding error? No way of knowing, and the method is too generic to pinpoint. Check out thee stack trace to see if you can pinpoint which method is doing this and what it is expecting to receive but isn't.